# Azure new VM account disabled by default (Custom Image)

Tags: azure, windows-10, virtual-machine, sysprep

I'm having trouble when creating a VM in Microsoft Azure using a custom windows image.

### Issue

When connecting to the newly spawned VM using the credentials entered in Azure Portal, I get the following message :

```
   The user account is currently disabled and cannot be used.
```

Running a `Get-LocalAccount` script using the "Run Command" menu of the Azure Portal I get the following output:

```
Name               Enabled Description                                                                                 
----               ------- -----------                                                                                                                                                                         
DefaultAccount     False   A user account managed by the system.                                                       
Guest              False   Built-in account for guest access to the computer/domain                                    
myusername         False   Built-in account for administering the computer/domain                                      
WDAGUtilityAccount False   A user account managed and used by the system for Windows Defender Application
```

### Workaround

If I use procedure from [Azure VM connection error - The user account is currently disabled and cannot be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022035/azure-vm-connection-error-the-user-account-is-currently-disabled-and-cannot-be), I'm able to unlock the user and connect to the VM via RDP.

I also try creating a new user prior to sysprepping the VM so the local admin account is renamed and disable by Azure during VM creation but the user account created remain enabled.

### Image Info

**OS**: Windows 10 LTSC 2019

**Source**: Custom deployed image used by my company. It was installed with an ISO on local HyperV machine, uploaded to Azure and SysPrep from a managed disk.

WindowsAzureVmAgent version 2.7.41491.949_191001-1418 installed on the VM prior to running sysprep.

### Step Taken

- Re-enabling the account and running Sysprep again to create a new snapshot does not fix the issue
- Renaming the local administrator account prior to Sysprep the device does not have any effect.
- Checked the local policies and nothing look unusual.

Comment: This would be a better fit on SuperUser or ServerFault. Unfortunately off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution with the help of Microsoft Azure support engineer. For a VM uploaded from on premise source, you would need to add a `SetupComplete2.cmd` and `EnableLocalAdminAccount.ps1` in `C:/Windows/OEM` to unlock the user account automatically upon VM creation. Strangely enough this does not appear on anywhere on Microsoft's guideline on how to migrate a on-prem VM to Azure, but the official windows image from the Marketplace do have those 2 files that are run after Sysprep.

This blog article was also very useful and points towards the creation of a SetupComplete2.cmd https://matt.kotsenas.com/posts/azure-setupcomplete2